# Pinholes in new cast iron pan

Tags: cast-iron

I just received my new cast-iron skillet and noticed two little pinholes (1-2mm) in the inside bottom of the pan (see pic below). As I live outside the USA, it is a hassle getting it returned and replaced. Will the pinholes become a food contamination hazard? Are there specific things I should avoid doing or consider doing because of the pinholes?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seasoned the pan yet?

https://www.southernliving.com/food/how-to/how-t0-season-a-cast-iron-skillet

I think the oil you use for seasoning will fill up those holes.  The other thing about a pan is that it gets hot and it is going to be hot in the holes.  No germs will survive down there.